# Breakup an UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt32> in swift 5.x

Tags: swift, image, pixel, raw-data, unsafemutablebufferpointer

iOS 15, Swift 5.5

Sorry, stupid easy question??

I am working on an image processing app, and I have this.

```
let pixels = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt32>(start: rawData, count: width * height)
```

Which I want to break into two pieces, so I tried this.

```
let fullSet = width * height
let halfSet = fullSet / 2
let pix1 = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt32>(start: rawData, count: halfSet)
let pix2 = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt32>(start: (rawData + halfSet), count: halfSet)
```

I suspect my problem is that the UInt32 is in fact a UInt24 + UInt8, as in red+green+blue and alpha channel.

I count the colours in my pixel Set and I got 120,433... but if I convert to an array I end up with 57,142.

Comment: Perhaps `let pix2 = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<UInt32>(start: (rawData + halfSet), count: fullSet - halfSet)`.

Comment: fullSet - halfSet is the same as halfSet

Comment: Does `rawData` have the type `UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt32>`? In that case your calculation (as show so far) is correct.

Comment: Yes it does, but I am corrupting the data within it then, because I got a lot more colours in the single pixels buffer, than I seem to have in the same buffer that I split in half?

Comment: Then more information and more code is needed: What is the exact format of the pixel data? How do you “count the colours” and “convert to an array”?

Comment: “fullSet - halfSet is the same as halfSet” … generally, but not always. If width and height are both odd, the `fullSet` will not be evenly divisible.

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

I found the answer, thanks everyone for your comments. And yes, it is stupid obvious, you just use a subset.

```
let pix1 = pixels[(0..<pixels.count / 2)]
let pix2 = pixels[(pixels.count / 2)...]
```

I was trying too hard I think.